# Cutting Rows to Create Sample in an Excel File

Tags: java, excel, data-mining

I'm working on a large excel spreadsheet for a datamining project related to housing costs. There are multiple sheets in this file each with 20-50 columns and around 20,000 rows.

For each sheet, I need to create two more sheets. One will contain a random sample of 10% of the rows. The other will contain the other 90% of rows not included in the sample. Are there any excel commands or plugins to easily achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

VBA Excel: You can start recording a macro in Excel. Then you do some major steps MANUALLY, while recording is ON. Then you stop recording and look at the macro.

Then, you can also run the macro on the original file (the file before you did something MANUALLY).

Maybe, this macro will also work for you, if just some values in the tables change.

Anyway, usually, you have to look at the code of the macro, and edit the code for the adaption of e.g. file name, number of columns, or whatever. If you are not sure about something - record just one MANUAL step and see which VBA command is invoked. OR as I said, really just change values in the sheet. And the original recorded macro, might already completely be okay to be run on the new values. You will find a lot of infos on VBA Excel - the start is: just record a macro ...